# Batch file exits when command run internally finishes

Tags: batch-file, windows-7

I'm creating a simple command line using Batch for a personal project. However, whenever I try to execute a batch file in it, the command line closes as soon as the batch file completes. Why is that, and how can I fix it?

This is the relevant bit of source (also an SSCCE):

```
@echo off
:loopstart
    set /p comnd=%cd%^>
    %comnd%
goto loopstart
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have comments but must give you an answer, so couple things:

The /p option in Set generates a prompt for user input, so it's waiting for an answer but you are not handling any user response.

You have set up an infinite loop with the goto at the end (but that doesn't necessarily cause CMD window to close).

Rem out the goto at end and add a pause and you should be able to track down the problem.

**EDIT: New answer per user's comments ---------------------------------------**

Use call in this bat and **exit /b at end of each bat** you're running from this prompt.

```
 :loopstart
 set /p comnd=%cd%^>
 call %comnd%
 goto loopstart
```

Comment: If you'll notice, this is meant to emulate a command line. Therefore, it *should* be taking user input; otherwise, it's useless as one. It loops infinitely because it is designed to -- running a single command is useless. It isn't modifying %cd%; rather, it's accessing it so that it can display `C:\Working\Directory\>` as the prompt instead of just `>`, like in the actual Windows command line. This doesn't answer my question in the slightest. I asked how to keep the command being run from closing the command line, and you replied with telling me to fix things that were put in by design. -1.

Comment: Okay. As said, I would have asked for clarification in comment if I could. In any case, have you tried debugging with the pause?

Comment: I have, and it still fails before the pause. Something when the command is run is quitting the command line. I don't know why you couldn't have just commented, though.

Comment: I don't have 50 rep ... and now it's a little lower. lol. FWIW, I ran it in editor with pause before answering and it did pause. Error occurred when entering anything at prompt.

Comment: New answer. That should work. This is nice method for running bats with qualifying names sequentially.

Comment: `call` seems to have done the trick for me. Thanks for the help!